# Swift: PrepareForSegue, Swift Cast failure

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I would like to select one cell in my `TableViewController`. The text of the cell should be transferred via segue to FirstViewController's label. I always get the error shown below.

The identifier is correct.

My code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "BackToCalculator") {
        //let myRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow().row+1
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as FirstViewController
        vc.SelectedBundesland.text = "Test"
    }
}
```

Exception:

> 0x103f1f5dc:  jne    0x103f1f5d0               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 48
>   0x103f1f5de:  leaq   0x3364d(%rip), %rax       ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
>   0x103f1f5e5:  movq   %rax, 0xa456c(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
>   0x103f1f5ec:  int3
>   0x103f1f5ed:  movq   %r14, %rax

**What is wrong?**

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the destination view controller is not an instance of `FirstViewController` - have you checked that? Which is the line raising the exception?

Comment: Can you tell me how to implement that the DestinationViewController is an instance of FirstViewController? I am new to Swift. Thanks in advance

Comment: That's more about iOS development than swift - my guess is that you don't even know how to do that in objective-c. So I suggest to read some documentation, and read some tutorials, such as [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1), and others available at the [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/) website - or just google.

Comment: In Objective C i added the DestVC.h into FirstVC.h. But this is not necessary anymore. Is there a way like this in swift?

Comment: No you don't need to do that in swift. Remove the `as FirstViewController` cast, put a breakpoint in the next
 line and check what's the actual type of `vc` - I think that to do that you have to comment the `vc.SelectedBunesland.text = "Test"` line out.

Comment: vc is "AnyObject!" The segue is connected to a tabbar controller. Could that be wrong?

Comment: After that it should report the `instance_type`, which is the actual type of the view controller - something like `vc = (AnyObject!) (instance_type = TestApp.FirstViewController)` - what's shown in your case?

Comment: [link](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3720/3paehsa6_png.htm)

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at the next line and in the console type `po vc!`, what's the output?

Comment: "no matches" when typing this in the console.. Breakpoint at line 108.. maybe it is because of my segue from TableViewController to TabViewController [link](http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/bildschirmfotoacf032quho.png)

Comment: Line 108 doesn't tell me anything... are you sure you've set the view controller's custom class property in IB to FirstViewController? If you remove the cast to 'FirstViewController' and comment the next line does it work or does it still throws the exception?

Comment: When i connect the segue directly to FirstViewController, the line `let vc = segue.destinationViewController as FirstViewController` works and vc is an object of FirstViewController. But the next line `vc.SelectedBundesland.text = "Test"` does not work: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 2):

May be late in the game but was getting the exact same issue.
The problem here was your Segue was pointing to the Tab controller rather than the actual ViewController where it needs to jump to. I am referring to the 2nd screenshot you have provided to Antonio. If you fix that it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

A much safer and forward approach is conditional cast, or even better protocol based, consider the following:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? FirstViewController {
        vc.SelectedBundesland.text = "Test"
    } else {
       print("Some other controller! \(segue.destinationViewController)")
    }
}
```

That certainly works. But if you have multiple segues and multiple viewController it can be quite a pain to swing information and data around.

Consider the protocol approach:

```
protocol BundeslandProtocol {
    var SelectedBundesland: String {get set}
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if var vc = segue.destinationViewController as? BundeslandProtocol {
        vc.SelectedBundesland.text = "Test"
    }
}
```

To make the above work you just have to declare your UIViewController to conform to said protocol:

```
class AwesomeViewController: UIViewController, BundeslandProtocol {
 .... 
}
```

Over time you'll be able to rename your classes, change them, replace and expand your project and you won't have to care about changing references around, as long as the protocol will keep its purpose.

It's not easy to tell where your code is broken: it usually happen when you forget to set your class name (FirstViewController in your case) in the storyboard, for the controller to which the segue is executed, see screenshot, it has to be set instead of UIViewController generic class.

[image: see screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar error - I believe that `segue.destinationViewController` is here a `UINavigationController`. You are getting an error because you are trying to cast a UINavigationController into your FirstViewController class.

Change this line:   `let vc = segue.destinationViewController as FirstViewController`

to this:  `let vc = segue.destinationViewController.topViewController as FirstViewController`

`.topViewController` is the top view controller on the navigation stack - which should now be an instance of `FirstViewController`

Answer (score 0):

Check your storyboard，I think you make the segue "point" to another viewController by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("BackToCalculator", sender: self)

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if (segue.identifier == "BackToCalculator") {
        //let myRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow().row+1
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as FirstViewController
        vc.SelectedBundesland.text = "Test"
}
```

U need to call self.performSegueWithIdentifier.